# Swift calling a class differences

Tags: swift, class

I'm trying to wrap my head around calling classes/structs from within classes and their implications within Swift and OOP. What I'm looking for is the differences between the following initialisations and their basis for use.

1.`let classA: classB!`

2.`let classA = classB()`

3. `let classA: classB = classB()`

The Apple documentation on this is a little overwhelming so I'm looking for a simple explanation if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Class names are uppercase and variable names lowercase. That would be much more readable this way: `let objectB = ClassB()`

Comment: to add to what redent said - in your examples, `classA` isn't a class but a variable. Calling it `classA` will work but it's like coding `let myDict = [Int]()` - `myDict` isn't a Dict, it's an Array. It's misleading.

Comment: Also, your question title doesn't reflect the question - you are not "calling classes/structs from within classes" - you are initialising variables.

Comment: Calling a class whether from a variable or another method is still calling a class. The grammar is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is declaring class as an `Optional`, it is not initialised (it is `nil`) until you set `classA = classB()`. `!` means, that if you will try to access it in some time - you are sure, it won't be `nil`. If `var classA: ClassB?` - compiler will ask you to unwrap it.

i.e. ! on the declaration means that the variable is an implicitly unwrapped optional - whenever you access it, you don't need ! as it will always be unwrapped, but you better make sure that the variable is not nil.

2. and 3. Is the same, you initialise class, so classA is now `ClassB` instance. You don't have to code `let classA: ClassB`, because in this case `classA` will be the same class you set it to be.

Comment: 2 and 3 are the same because in 2) you are saying "let variable classA be of type classB and equal to a new classB object" whereas in 3, you don;t have to tell Swift that classA is of type classB because Swift knows (infers) that because the initialiser for classB returns an object of type classB.  In Objective-C you had to explicitly tell the compiler the type of all variables  - you don't with Swift.

Answer (score 1):

1.**`let classA: classB!`**

This statement creates a `constant classA` of `type classB`. This is a `forced unwrapped optional` constant, i.e. it cannot have a `nil` value. Also while using `classA` constant, you don't need to unwrap it.

2.**`let classA = classB()`**

This statement creates a `constant classA` and assigns an `object of classB` to it. Type of constant `classA` is inferred from the value assigned to it.

3.**`let classA: classB = classB()`**

This statement creates a `constant classA` of `type classB` and then assigns an `object of classB` to it. Explicitly defining the type of `classA` is optional in this statement. i.e. it is equivalent to the 2nd statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
let classA: ClassB!
```

This declares an implicitly unwrapped optional constant. The type of `classA` is `Optional<ClassB>`. It's the same as declaring an ordinary optional except that every time `classA` is used in an expression, there is an implicit `!` straight after it. This means that it can be nil (in fact it effectively starts out as nil) but if you try to use it when it is nil, your program will crash.

Note that, because it is a `let`, you only get to assign a value to it once. It's much more common to use this with `var`.

There are very few occasions when you should be using an implicitly unwrapped optional. You'll most commonly see it in `IBOutlet`s where the property cannot be initialised during `init` but, on the other hand, it should never be nil after the nib has been loaded.

```
let classA = ClassB()
```

This is a normal declaration of a let constant. It's initialised to a new instance of ClassB and can never be changed. The type of classA is known through *type inference*. The compiler figures it out by looking at the type of the expression on the right hand side of the `=` and using that.

If ClassB is a struct, the whole of the instance including its internal properties are constant. If it's a class, then only the reference is constant. Properties in the instance can still be changed.

```
let classA: ClassB = ClassB()
```

This statement explicitly gives `classA` type `ClassB` and then initialises it with a new instance of classB. Because classA is given the same type as the right hand side of the assignment, it is functionally identical to the previous example. Therefore, because it is less typing, you'll normally see the previous example used. There are two occasions I can think of where you *have* to use this form.

- if you have a class hierarchy and you explicitly want the constant to be the super class e.g.

  ```
  class B {}
  class C: B {} // C is a subclass of B
  let a: B = C() // a is a B but initialised specifically to a C
  ```
- if you have a generic function where only the return type tells you which concrete type to use e.g.

  ```
  func doSomething<T>() -> T { ... }
  let a: ClassB = doSomething()
  ```

  In the above example, the compiler can only infer `T` by seeing what its result will be assigned to. Therefore, the left hand side must be explicitly typed.